# C++ gSOAP wsdl types

Tags: c++, soap, wsdl, gsoap

I'm working on a .wsdl file to define a service for gSOAP. In one of the service's requests, I want to use a user defined type as part of the request, but I can't get it right, and don't know what the problem is:

```
<definitions name="Uploader"
    targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl"
    xmlns:tns="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl"
    [...]>
[...]
<types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <element name="FileInformation">
            <complexType><all>
                <element name="sFilename" type="string"/>
                <element name="bDirectory" type="boolean"/>
            </all></complexType>
        </element>

        [...]

        <element name="UploadRequest">
            <complexType><all>
                <element name="fileInfo" type="tns:FileInformation"/>
            </all></complexType>
        </element>

        [...]

    </schema>
</types>
[...]
</definitions>
```

When I try to generate header files out of it with `wsdl2h -o Uploader.h http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl` the `fileInfo` member will be defined as a string and I get the following warning:

```
Warning: could not find element 'fileInfo' type '"http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl":FileInformation' in schema http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to write a few WSDL files myself, however I discovered that they are very difficult to get right, mainly because of the XML namespaces, so I would recommend that you write your classes in C++ and generate the WSDL file automatically from them instead of doing it the other way around.

If that is not possible I would suggest that take a look at this [thread](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/xml-xslt-and-xpath/threads/279033). I think that if you change your schema to something like this, it might work:

```
<definitions name="Uploader"
targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl"
xmlns:tns="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl">

<types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://192.168.2.113/uploader/uploader.wsdl"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

       <xsd:element name="FileInformation" type="tns:FileInformation" />
       <xsd:complexType name="FileInformation">
           <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="sFilename" type="string"/>
                <xsd:element name="bDirectory" type="boolean"/>
            </xsd:all>
       </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:element name="UploadRequest" type="tns:UploadRequest"/>
        <xsd:complexType name="UploadRequest">
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="fileInfo" type="tns:FileInformation"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>

   </schema>
</types>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch. Yes, I should really start using generated files. I'm thinking I'd understand SOAP better if I do stuff like this myself first.

Comment: You are welcome! I've gone through your problem myself and believe me, writing WSDL files your self can be really complicated...